# changing select dropdown arrow next to each option

Tags: html, css

I have added this style to my css file for all select inputs

```
select {
    border:1px solid #666666;;
    width:100%;
    height:26px;
    font-size:12px;
    margin:0 0 20px 0;
    padding-left:10px;
    float:right;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    background-image:url('../../images/dropdown.png');
    background-size:25px;
    background-position:98% 50%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border-radius:0;
}
```

how can i make my arrow look like the on in these boxes? - http://postimg.org/image/4qvumqoc1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a Bootstrap 3 glyphicon in an html select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19259518/how-to-use-a-bootstrap-3-glyphicon-in-an-html-select) check that link and see the correct answer there, could help you out as well.

Comment: i want to be able to add it into my CSS not HTML

Answer (score 0):

```
select {
    border:1px solid #666666;;
    width:100%;
    height:26px;
    font-size:12px;
    margin:0 0 20px 0;
    padding-left:10px;
    float:right;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    background-image:url('../../images/dropdown.png');
    background-size:25px;
    background-position:98% 50%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border-radius:0;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: '';
}
```

Here's the fiddle with : http://jsfiddle.net/6hMua/

Comment: is there anyway i can use HTML code rather than a background image?