# JQGrid 4.7 display font awesome or image icons in edit type select

Tags: jqgrid

Can anyone suggest how to display font awesome or my own image icons in drop-down select when jqgrid is in line edit mode? Icons will be static and will never change.
Thank you.

Comment: You may want to [look at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19259518/how-to-use-a-bootstrap-3-glyphicon-in-an-html-select/26936511#26936511)

Comment: bootstrap-select is not compatible with Bootstrap 4 yet. Icon uni codes partially work and not in all browsers. Is it possible to use this in jqgrid when it is in line edit mode    <div class="btn-group"> with ul li items like described in the link? Thank you

Comment: Yes I think this is possiblen with custom element in this case. Wonder how jqGrid 4.7 support Bootstrap 4!