# Flaticon in select option

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, icons

I want to show flaticons in options but html output doesn't display them.

[How to display Icon in select options tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54002590/how-to-display-icon-in-select-options-tag)

Above question is solved by using `&#xf2bb` instead of icon class like that:

```
 <option value="fa fa-address-card"> &#xf2bb; line chart</option>
```

If it is possible, how can I solve this problem with the same solution method for flaticons?

flaticon.css contains below style:

```
.flaticon-tool:before {
    content: "\f177";
```

my html output:

```
    <select class="form-control" name="hekim-extension_ozellikler_icon-select" id="hekim-extension_ozellikler_icon-select">
<option>flaticon-throat</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

If it is possible and easy, also I can use a solution for boootstrap 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no valid solution to put icons into a `select` option. My solution is using a [jQuery icon picker](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Searchable-FontAwesome-Icon-Picker-jQuery-Simple-Iconpicker.html).