# Icon font in select field not working on most browsers

Tags: html, css, select, icons

I'm trying to use an icon font in an HTML select field, but it seems only to show correctly in Chrome. I'm using RemixIcon, because I need several special icons like the whatsapp-symbol. I tried it like this:

```
<select style="font-family: 'remixicon' !important;" class="form-control customize-icon-select" name="myselect">
                <option class="option-no-icon" value="">- no icon -</option>                
                <option style="font-family: 'remixicon' !important;" value="ri-phone-fill">&#xEFE9;</option>
</select>
```

The icon only shows correctly in the select field when it's already selected, but not in the dropdown.

This is how it looks in Chrome:
[image]

And in Firefox & Chrome on Android: [image]

What can I do to make the icon show up without using a custom dropdown field?

Comment: Maybe check this SO answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54002590/how-to-display-icon-in-select-options-tag)

Comment: Are the icon fonts hosted locally? try that if not and see that helps

Comment: Please consider using SVG icons instead of icon fonts, for this exact reason [and many others](https://cloudfour.com/thinks/seriously-dont-use-icon-fonts/)